# An Akka/Scala promise that requires two actors to complete

Tags: scala, transactions, akka, promise, future

I am building a stock market application using Scala and Akka. The market matches buyers and sellers and then sends a

```
Promise[Transaction]
```

to both the buyer and the seller that needs to be completed (at some point) in order for the transaction to be processed.

Issue is that the promise could complete with failure because either

1. buyer has insufficient funds,
2. seller has insufficient shares.

How can I create a Scala promise that requires the coordination of two actors to complete?

Comment: How about sending two `ask` messages to both the buyer and seller, then use a `for-comprehension` to return the wanted promise?

Comment: Wouldn't this require the market to wait for both the buyer and seller to respond? I would prefer for the market to simply generate promises and have either (or both) the buyer and seller wait (if necessary).

Comment: please remember to accept an answer if it responded to your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right not to want to use `ask` -- that should be avoided when possible.

Here is how you can send Promises to buyer and seller actors, then compose the corresponding Futures and arrange to process the transaction when the Promises are fulfilled.

```
import scala.concurrent.{future, promise}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val  fundsPromise = promise[Funds]
val sharesPromise = promise[Shares]

 buyerActor ! GetFunds(amount, fundsPromise)
sellerActor ! GetShares(numShares, stock, sharesPromise)

val futureFunds =   fundsPromise.future
val futureShares = sharesPromise.future

val purchase =
  for { funds <- futureFunds; shares <- futureShares }
    yield transact(funds, shares)

purchase onComplete {
  case Success(transactionResult) =>
     buyerActor ! PutShares(numShares)
    sellerActor ! PutFunds(amount)
    // tell somebody it worked
  case Failure(t) =>
    futureFunds  onSuccess { case _ =>  buyerActor ! PutFunds(amount) }
    futureShares onSuccess { case _ => sellerActor ! PutShares(numShares) }
    // tell somebody it failed because of t
}
```

Note that the ultimate result can be failure for several reasons: because you could not get the funds from the buyer, because you could not get the shares from the seller, or because something went wrong in `transact`.  So on failure we check the funds and shares futures to see whether we got them, and if so we give back what we took.

Also note that we close over `amount` and `numShares` in futures, which means that you want them to be vals.  If they were vars, you could end up using the wrong values when the futures actually run.

As bsmk points out, this assumes that `buyerActor` and `sellerActor` are in the same JVM as the above code.  If not, you could have a local actor handle the promise upon hearing from the remote actor; if there is a better way, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: This is much closer to what I was originally thinking. Why do you think this will cause transactions to queue up? Some more background: there is not a single buyer actor or seller actor, but rather many buyers and sellers (I have run a model with order of 1e5 to 1e6 buyer/seller actors so far). Currently a market actor matches a particular buyer actor with a particular seller actor at some price and quantity. Market then sends this information as a message to relevant actors and goes back to matching other buyer actors and seller actors.

Comment: Ah, I see -- when you said two actors, you meant two actors involved in the transaction, not that there is a single buyer actor and a single seller actor.  I read too much into it.  And I'm guessing that you *do* want to serialize the requests for a given buyer/seller, because they have to update the state -- funds and shares.  You are right on track then, David, and I have updated my answer.

Comment: it would appear that `futureFunds  onSuccess {  buyerActor ! PutFunds(amount) }` is invalid as ` buyerActor ! PutFunds(amount)` is not a partial function. Is there anyway you could modify your answer accordingly?

Comment: Sure.  I also added some notes at the end.

Comment: As promise is not immutable and serializable, this will not work for cluster. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following:

```
def querySellingActor(seller : ActorRef) : Future[Boolean] = ???
def queryBuyingActor(buyer : ActorRef ) : Future[Boolean] = ???

// Calling these outside the for-comprehension 
// ensures that they are really parallel
val f1 = querySellingActor(sellerActor)
val f2 = queryBuyingActor(buyerActor)

val niceResult = for{
   sellerCanSell <- f1
   buyerCanBuy <- f2
} yield { sellerCanSell && buyerCanBuy }
```

`niceResult` is now a Future[Boolean] that can be passed around and you can install your call-backs on it.

Comment: It is crucial that the market not wait: the market can not query actor's and wait for a response. I don't see how I could use this solution in my context without effectively burying it in a short-lived actor pattern similar to @EndeNeu's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the short lived actor pattern, you should use the `ask` pattern only if you really need to:

```
case object TransactionTimeout
case class NewTransaction(buyer: ActorRef, seller: ActorRef)

class TransactionHandlerActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  var _scheduled: Cancellable = null
  var resultReceiver = Actor.noSender
  var hasBuyerAnswered = false
  var hasSellerAnswered = false

  def receive: Receive = {
    case NewTransaction(buyer, seller) =>
      resultReceiver = sender()
      buyer ! BuyRequest(...)
      seller ! SellRequest(...)
      _scheduled = context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5 seconds)(self ! TransactionTimeout)

    case TransactionTimeout =>
      resultReceiver ! TransactionError(...)
      context.stop(self)

    case BuyerResponse(...) =>
      hasBuyerAnswered = true
      checkIfComplete()
    case SellerResponse(...) =>
      hasSellerAnswered = true
      checkIfComplete()
  }

  def checkIfComplete() = {
    if(hasBuyerAnswered && hasSellerAnswered) {
      /* finalize operation */
      resultReceiver ! TransactionCompleted(...)
      _scheduled.cancel()
      context.stop(self)
    }
  }
}
```

Basically the temporary actor handles the transaction and stops himself when finished, the timeout is there to ensure that he won't wait forever for a response. This is a very simple example of what you can do, code is untested.

Comment: Seems a reasonable approach. However I am particular keen to use a promise if possible (or to understand why a promise is not appropriate/possible to use in this context).

Comment: If you really want to use promises and futures you should use the ask pattern, but be advise that with `ask` akka simply instantiate a temporary actor, which is exactly what I'm doing, with the difference that you don't have control over it, what I mean is, akka assigns as name an identifier and in case of failure you have only that. Usually ask is a code smell, there's always a way to avoid that, it only needs more thinking, but again, there are some use cases were it fits, yours doesn't seems like one though.