# Is sending futures in Akka messages OK?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, concurrent.futures

I'm working on implementing a small language to send tasks to execution and control execution flow. After the sending a task to my system, the user gets a future (on which it can call a blocking get() or flatMap() ). My question is: is it OK to send futures in Akka messages?

Example: actor A sends a message *Response* to actor B and *Response* contains a future among its fields. Then at some point A will fulfill the promise from which the future was created. After receiving the *Response*, B can call flatMap() or get() at any time.

I'm asking because Akka messages should be immutable and work even if actors are on different JVMs. I don't see how my example above can work if actors A and B are on different JVMs. Also, are there any problems with my example even if actors are on same JVM?

Something similar is done in the accepted answer [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982265/an-akka-scala-promise-that-requires-two-actors-to-complete). Will this work if actors are on different JVMs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without remoting it's possible, but still not advisable. With remoting in play it won't work at all.

If your goal is to have an API that returns `Future`s, but uses actors as the plumbing underneath, one approach could be that the API creates its own actor internally that it `ask`s, and then returns the future from that ask to the caller. The actor spawned by the API call is guaranteed to be local to the API instance and can communicate with the rest of the actor system via the regular `tell`/`receive` mechanism, so that there are no `Future`s sent as messages.

```
class MyTaskAPI(actorFactory: ActorRefFactory) {

   def doSomething(...): Future[SomethingResult] = {
     val taskActor = actorFactory.actorOf(Props[MyTaskActor])
     taskActor ? DoSomething(...).mapTo[SomethingResult]
   }
 }
```

where `MyTaskActor` receives the `DoSomething`, captures the sender, sends out the request for task processince and likely `become`s a receiving state for `SomethingResult` which finally responds to the captured sender and stops itself. This approach creates two actors per request, one explicitly, the `MyTaskActor` and one implicitly, the handler of the `ask`, but keeps all state inside of actors.

Alternately, you could use the [ActorDSL](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actordsl.html) to create just one actor inline of `doSomething` and use a captured `Promise` for completion instead of using `ask`:

```
class MyTaskAPI(system: System) {

   def doSomething(...): Future[SomethingResult] = {
     val p = Promise[SomethingResult]()
     val tmpActor = actor(new Act {
       become {
         case msg:SomethingResult => 
            p.success(msg)
            self.stop()
       }
     }
     system.actorSelection("user/TaskHandler").tell(DoSomething(...), tmpActor)
     p.future
   }
 }
```

This approach is a bit off the top of my head and it does use a shared value between the API and the temp actor, which some might consider a smell, but should give an idea how to implement your workflow.

Comment: This is a good answer to the question, I've marked it as the answer. However, I can have millions of tasks in my system at once, so I would like to avoid creating actors for each task for performance issues. I'll make it a requirement that the relevant parts of the system (actors A and B in my example) are on the same JVM and return futures.

Comment: If your processing actor simply queues tasks using a promise/future to signal eventual processing and then completion, this whole thing might be as simple as using `ask` directly. that way your processing actor still gets a simple message and instead of creating a `Promise` and returning it immediately, it stores the `sender` and does a `tell` on it on completion. The `ask` handles turning this into a `Future`

Comment: @ArneClaassen: Why won't remote actors work in the scenario he described?

Comment: In the ask scenario remitting will work just fine since the future you get back is a local construct. The more involved approaches above assumed you had a more complicated workflow in mind.  I can write up a separate answer just for the ask scenario, if that is more fitting to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if it's possible, then yes, it's possible. Remote actors are basically interprocess communication. If you set everything up on both machines to a state where both can properly handle the future, then it should be good. You don't give any working example so I can't really delve deeper into it.